# Start A New Android Studio Project and Project Structure Do Nothing. (welcome Screen)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I searched for this but could not find any answers.
I set up my Android Studio IDE and after that I clicked on Start Project at the welcome screen. It said I wasn't pointed to the correct SDK path. 
So, I went ahead and updated the same at  Project Defaults > Project Structure. 
But as soon as I hit Apply, nothing happens. 
After this, Project Defaults never opens again. And Start A New Project is unresponsive. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE: I've tried to Go offline for Gradle and Also changed my HTTP Proxy settings and tested the connection. These are not causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having Android Studio is not enough to create an Android project. You have to download SDK tools and Android APIs as well. You can do it through SDK Manager

Comment: Downloaded and Installed

Comment: Make sure the min, max and target SDK of your project is within the range of the SDK(s) you downloaded

Answer (score 0):

It must be downloading that particular version of sdk/buildtools  in the background from internet. Android Studio does not believe in showing you progress or any errors. I faced that issue. Either sit patiently with that blank Android Studio screen for half day or full day with internet connection on or change your default sdk to some vrsion which you have. This should fix.

To change default sdk version:

File>Project Structure> in the modules section choose your app > on the right you have the default build tools version ( refer Image). Make sure you already have the version downloaded , ehich  you choose here, else you will see the same behaviour.
[image]

Comment: @Abhid Updated my answer , pls check.

Comment: This is the first time I'm opening Android Studio and As I mentioned before, now the Project Structure is not opening too. :(